# How to make custom baseline for `TextFormField` in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, baseline, textformfield

I want to create a custom baseline for `TextFormField` in Flutter. The example for what I wanna do is given below.

[image]

Comment: You would need to override either the `paint` or `getOuterPath` method of `UnderlineInputBorder`, I will try to write an example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom input border which would extend `UnderlineInputBorder`. What you need to override is the `paint` method.
I implemented here in this manner so that you can easily add colors and it would then draw lines for you giving same width to each color, but feel free to update it for your needs.
That would be something like this:

```
class CustomInputBorder extends UnderlineInputBorder {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect,
      {double gapStart,
      double gapExtent = 0.0,
      double gapPercentage = 0.0,
      TextDirection textDirection}) {
    drawLines(
        canvas, rect, [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.blue, Colors.orange]);
  }

  void drawLines(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, List<Color> colors) {
    var borderWidth = rect.bottomRight.dx - rect.bottomLeft.dx;
    var sectionWidth = borderWidth / colors.length;
    var startingPoint = rect.bottomLeft;
    var endPoint = getEndPoint(startingPoint, sectionWidth);

    colors.forEach((color) {
      var paint = Paint();
      paint.color = color;
      paint.strokeWidth = 1.0;

      canvas.drawLine(startingPoint, endPoint, paint);

      startingPoint = getNewStartingPoint(startingPoint, sectionWidth);
      endPoint = getEndPoint(startingPoint, sectionWidth);
    });
  }

  Offset getNewStartingPoint(Offset oldStartingPoint, double width) {
    return Offset(oldStartingPoint.dx + width, oldStartingPoint.dy);
  }

  Offset getEndPoint(Offset startingPoint, double width) {
    return Offset(startingPoint.dx + width, startingPoint.dy);
  }
}
```

And then you can use it:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Username',
    border: CustomInputBorder(),
    enabledBorder: CustomInputBorder(),
    focusedBorder: CustomInputBorder(),
  ),
),
```

This is how it looks like right now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDTBu.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4SjM.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5aW8.png

Comment: Adding to the answer above, you should have to add `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` above `CustomInputBorder` to make things work. And also you will have to modify paint method by replacing `double gapStart` with `double? gapStart` and `TextDirection textDirection` with `TextDirection? textDirection`

Comment: True, if you are using null safety, you have to change those two.
Imports are kinda self-explanatory but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

First place worth looking at is the [UnderlineInputBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/UnderlineInputBorder-class.html) class. You should be able to set the `decoration:` of a `TextFormField` as an `InputDecoration`, which can take an `UnderlineInputBorder` as its `border:`. You should then be able to style the border's `BorderSide' property appropriately to match your design.